# Xml tags printing differently in Restcontroller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, xml-parsing

I am using a controller for post mapping in spring

```
@PostMapping(value ="/HttpNoRespAdapter",consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    protected String process(@RequestBody String request, HttpServletResponse response)  {


        }
```

I am taking whatever coming in the requestbody as string, the following xml should come

```
<REQ><FEATURE>DELIVERY-RECEIPT</FEATURE><TIME-STAMP><![CDATA[20200925190730]]></TIME-STAMP><TRANSACTION-ID><![CDATA[71554]]></TRANSACTION-ID><SMPP-ID><![CDATA[airtel]]></SMPP-ID><COMMAND-ID><![CDATA[5]]></COMMAND-ID><OA><![CDATA[8407600010]]></OA><DA><![CDATA[555]]></DA><DCS><![CDATA[0]]></DCS><SMS><![CDATA[stat:DELIVRD err:000 Text:silent]]></SMS><MESSAGE-ID><![CDATA[19]]></MESSAGE-ID></REQ>
```

But it coming as

```
%3CREQ%3E%3CFEATURE%3EDELIVERY-RECEIPT%3C%2FFEATURE%3E%3CTIME-STAMP%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B20201007175019%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FTIME-STAMP%3E%3CTRANSACTION-ID%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B60564%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FTRANSACTION-ID%3E%3CSMPP-ID%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bairtel%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSMPP-ID%3E%3CCOMMAND-ID%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B5%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FCOMMAND-ID%3E%3COA%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B8007600010%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FOA%3E%3CDA%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B555%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FDA%3E%3CDCS%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B0%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FDCS%3E%3CSMS%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5Bid%3A69+sub%3A001+dlvrd%3A001+submit+date%3A2010071750+done+date%3A2010071750+stat%3ADELIVRD+err%3A000+Text%3Asilent%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FSMS%3E%3CMESSAGE-ID%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B69%5D%5D%3E%3C%2FMESSAGE-ID%3E%3C%2FREQ%3E=
```

the xmltags are been replaced wrongly. how can i rectify this??

Comment: is there any java method or parsing technique to avoid this??

Comment: i think it is getting converted into UTF -8 . is there any method to decode it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use java.net.URLDecoder:

```
request = URLDecoder.decode(request, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: it is working, but one extra character  is coming, how can i remove the end character alone??

Comment: Which extra tag?

Comment: "=" is coming at the end, and that is again resulting in the parse exception

Comment: Well, it comes in the request and cannot be removed by URLDecoder. If you need to prepare this string for XML parsing, you can strip unneeded characters in the end by calling `request = request.substring(0, request.lastIndexOf(">") + 1);`.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-1dT0RnnFiWZqdP5T6OdfzkfSytIgJHdMgYD5-Xwaqk/edit?usp=sharing 
pls refer this, u can see that end tag

Comment: how can i write a validation condition?? i need to validate against the requests that only come with utf encoded?? others shud go as normal without decoding

Comment: i need a logic to check the first character of the string and compare it with a set of character and do the operation